# Loding Login/Other Form/View Error to create first time Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Server Error in '/' Application.
The layout page "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{                    
  ViewBag.Title  =  "Index";    
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```